# How to copy text, open website, then paste text using VBS

Tags: text, vbscript, copy, paste

Basically I would like to copy a text, open a website, then paste that text and press enter. Help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy a text file by using the File System Object.

```
Dim objFSO, objTextFile, objIE
Dim strTextFile, strTextLine
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Set up the origin and destination files   
strTextFile = "C:\myFile.txt"

' Open the temporary text file for reading
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strTextFile)

' Read the temporary text file
strTextLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
```

Once you have the text copied, you open the website.

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

objIE.Navigate "http://www.google.com"

Do Until objIE.readyState = 4 : Wscript.Sleep 10 : Loop
```

Next, you need to know the name of the field you are pasting into. This can be done by right-clicking and viewing the source code.

```
objIE.document.all.item("field_name").value = strTextLine
```

Finally, you use sendkeys to emulate the Enter key.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```